# Grab the last 2 of a split string, python

Tags: python, substring, delimiter

I've got a set of file directories that I am manipulating with python. However, all I care about is the last two levels of the directory. So if I had

```
"topdirectory/sub1/subsub1/subsubsub1/target"
"topdirectory/sub1/target"
```

The necesary returned strings would be

```
"subsubsub1/target"
```

and

```
"sub1/target"
```

I know python has a split string type method, but how can I tell it to only grab the LAST 2 components separated by delimeters?

Edit : Sorry guys, I should have explained that this is not REALLY a directory/file setup, but a timeseries DB that very closely resembles one. I figured it would just be easier to explain that way. The paths are essentially directories/files, but since it is a database, using the OS utilites wouldn't have any effect.

Comment: A quick dirty way: `>>> a = "topdirectory/sub1/subsub1/subsubsub1/target"
>>> a.split("/", a.count("/")-1)[-1]
'subsubsub1/target'`
Probably optimizable with a built-in function (and by looking in the doc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
"topdirectory/sub1/subsub1/subsubsub1/target".rsplit('/',2)[-2:]
```

This approach works for any string in general.

But as stated in the comments, if you refer to the system path, I'd rather use `os` module as suggested by Sean Perry. Note that on different operating system, delimiter can be different, etc.

Comment: As long as you know that there are two or more pieces. Otherwise this is an exception waiting to happen.

Comment: there will at the very least always be those two. Or rather, 3. The topdirectory is always there, and due to the way I have implented, it makes no logical sense to have 1 directory w/o the other.

Comment: one last thing, I need the final 2 in string form, not list. I know a workaround, but is there something like 

path.rsplit(':', 2)[-2:].join(":")

Comment: @Zack Even if you're sure of how you *want* something to be implemented, you can't always be sure that your program will be doing what you want or expect it to do. Because of this, sometimes when you're working on another part of the program, this part will be failing but in a way you didn't expect. That's why it's always good to check for errors, and give yourself specific failure messages to make debugging easier. If I were you, I would put in a `try/catch`. That will try (and execute) this code and if it fails, you can give yourself a specific warning of "Oh, it had less than 2 dirs!"

Comment: @jwarner112 fair enough.

Comment: @Zack That practice might save you a few hours of debugging one day, you never know :)

Comment: @SeanPerry I don't really think there will be an exception if you use negative index, try `[1][-2:]` gives you `[1]`

Comment: Fair enough @JánVorčák, but seriously, magic numbers in code is asking for trouble. Plus, some day you will want the last three or only the last one if the file is in /etc.

Comment: @Zack: The `join` you're looking for exists, but it works the other way around—as a method on the joining string, not on the list. So, `':'.join(path.rsplit(':', 2)[-2])`. (Although I'm not sure why you put colons in your comment, when there are slashes in the actual question, and probably in your real paths as well, unless you're on classic Mac OS or something…)

Comment: @SeanPerry I totally agree with what you've just written in the comments, I just wanted to point out that it will not throw an exception

Comment: @Zack: You really should look at Sean Perry's answer (and use `os.path.join` for the second half of your problem); you'll be happier in the long run.

Comment: view my comment on his post.

Answer (score 4):

The `os.path` module contains a `split` function for this. It returns the dirname and the basename. Run it twice and you have the last two bases.

Obviously, you want some checking that there are two or more bases as well.

Comment: +1. It's always a good idea to use `os.path` instead of string manipulation when dealing with paths. It handles all the portability issues and odd corner cases you don't think of during initial development, so you don't have to come back to your code 6 months later and figure out why it doesn't work on Windows or when the cwd is a symlink or whatever…

Comment: ok. I will let you know the reason I didn't go with this one is because I'm not actually dealing with a file structure, but a time series database that very closely resembles a file/directory structure. It was just easier to explain that way. I'm afraid using OS utilies won't be of much use to me.